# XML cannot be resolved or is not a field when combining Android projects

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, parse-platform

Hi I am working to overlay a Google [Heatmap](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/heatmap) within the map in the Parse.com [Anywall](https://parse.com/tutorials/anywall-android) app. I am getting errors where the XML files within the Anywall app are not being recognized by the Java file. I get the errors on the XML files such as:

> menu cannot be resolved or is not a field

I see that the XML files do not have any errors in the res folder. To restate, I am loading the Google heatmap to the Anywall app. I am worried the project is not calling from the proper R file. Does anyone have a suggestion? I have been adding/removing libraries from the Anywall project, cleaning the project, and restarting Eclipse. Thanks! I'm working on this app as part of my thesis project.

Here's part of the Java file:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
  public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class));
    return true;
  }
});
```

This is a screen capture of the Java file.

[image: Here's the screen capture of the errors.]

This is the XML.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: Where this XML is located? You placed it on `/res/menu` folder?

Comment: Yes. It seems like my project might not be calling from the correct R file. When I delete the call to inflate the menu up to `R.` there is not a suggestion for menu in the picklist that appears. Same thing with deleting `action_settings`.

Comment: Have you tried to `Clean Project`? After Clean, try to build the project and if you have any issue on any xml, the `R` class will not be generated. So you can track any other problem.

Comment: Yep, I've cleaned the project numerous times. I had to rebuild the app back to its basic state last night. I'm going to try adding the heatmap to the Anywall app again. Will post here if I need advice. Thanks!